# IOS/Objective-C: JSON response testing for nil and null

Tags: ios, objective-c, json, null

I receive some JSON that consists of results, response and if a query is successful, a value for success of 1.  If a query is not successful, there is no value in the JSON for success set.  What I would like to do is test for the value of success of 1, however, my code to detect this is throwing an exception.

```
NSDictionary *jsonResults = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:data options:NSJSONReadingMutableContainers error:nil];
NSDictionary *jsonresponse = jsonResults[@"response"];
if (![jsonResults isKindOfClass:[NSNull class]]
    &&![jsonResults[@"response"]isKindOfClass:[NSNull class]]
    &&![jsonResults[@"response"][@"success"]isKindOfClass:[NSNull class]]){
    //CODE BREAKS BEFORE GETTING HERE
    NSLog(@"got here");
```

This is what the JSON on fail looks like when logged to console:

```
{
    code = 400;
    error = "0(NSNull)";
    response = "Bad Request-No id found";
}
```

How would I fashion a test for a value set of success that would not throw an exception upon receiving the above?

Thanks in advance for any suggestions.

Comment: What's the error and which line exactly is causing it?

Comment: The error was LLB and occured at the line: if (![jsonResults isKindOfClass:[NSNull class]]... Since it is my api, I was able to stop the error by changing the API response to include a value for success  (on fail of 0) from which it seems that the reference to[jsonResults[@"response"][@"success"] is what caused the exception.  However, I still don't really know why  a reference to this caused the exception.  (I did try bt but could not understand it).

Comment: The error was not `llb`. That's the debugger prompt. The error will appear in the console.

Comment: Just noticed it, NSDictionary *jsonresponse = jsonResults[@"response"]; jsonresponse isnt a dictionary its a string.so you can try NSString *jsonresponse = jsonResults[@"response"]; or NSObject *jsonresponse = jsonResults[@"response"];

Comment: can you show your API call? Have you tested in Postman API?

Answer (score 0):

Rather than checking the error string or response, you should really check the reply code instead (ie 400, 200, etc). A list of standard codes are available here: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_HTTP_status_codes

Comment: Even manually, you should use the standard codes as well. And detecting the error based on codes are the way to go instead of detecting strings which could change in future.